# rdlc report not showing the report

Tags: c#, winforms, report, rdlc

i am showing rdlc report but it gives me the error (the report definition for "RptAttendence.rdlc" report not specified). Here is my code what am i doing wron with it? thanks in advance.

```
private void RptAttendence_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\jani\Documents\saloo.accdb");
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Student.Name, Student.FName,Class.Name As Class, [Section].Name As [Section], Attendence.Attendence, Attendence.Dat As [Date] From " +
                    "(((Attendence Inner join Student on Attendence.StudentID =Student.ID) inner join Class on Attendence.ClassID= Class.ID) inner join [Section] ON Attendence.SectionID = [Section].ID)";
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                adapter.Fill(table);

                reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Attendence.RptAttendence.rdlc";

                ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("Dataset1", table);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
                this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio - I think your problem will be solved by right clicking your report in the solution explorer and going into properties.

In properties change the build action to `Embedded Resource` and run your project again